# Determining number of chimeras made of three cell types from two individuals

Tags: combinatorics

Chimeras are made of three main cell types, A, B and C. Each cell type can come from individual 1 or individual 2. How many different chimeras are there and what formula do you use to figure this out?

Comment: I'm guessing (but could be wrong) that you mean all three cell types are represented, and that each comes from either individual $1$ or $2$ (not both).  In that case, there are $8$ different combinations ($=2^3$).  Two of those aren't really "chimeras", though, because all three cell types come from the same individual.

Comment: Is the chimera with A = 1, B = 1, C = 2 different from the chimera with A = 1, B = 2, and C = 1?

Comment: @mjqxxxx: thanks for the response. You are right, two are not really chimeras because all three cell types are from one individual.

Comment: @AustinMohr: yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

You might visualize the problem with Cells A, B, and C as "blanks".

```
_ _ _
A B C
```

Into each blank must be inserted either a 1 or a 2, depending on which individual contributed to that cell. You can make two choices for $A$ *followed by* two choices for $B$ *followed by* two choices for $C$. How can you determine the total number of possibilities based on this information?

As mentioned in the comments, the argument above counts *all* possible ways to assign numbers 1 or 2 to the blanks. Two of these configurations, however, do not meet the criterion of being a chimera, namely "111" and "222". We should therefore take our previous count and subtract 2 to get the number of configurations that actually correspond to chimeras.